# Vector3.Lerp not working on my camera

Tags: c#, android, iphone, unity-game-engine

I have a cube gameObject with a 2d collider, when someone hit the camera should be up 10 units, but smoothly, camera go to right position but no damping.

```
public Transform target;
public float damping = 0.1f;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Vector3 newPoint = Vector3.Lerp(target.transform.position,
                                    target.transform.position + Vector3.up * 10.0f,
                                    damping);

    target.transform.position = newPoint;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine you need to finish the movement animation of `other`, then. Try starting a coroutine for that, and make sure you don't start it again for the same collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you are not using Lerp properly.  This is how the mathematics of Linear Interpolation (Lerp) work:

Say we have a point `(0, 0)` and a point `(1, 1)`.  In order to calculate in between points, we provide a `t` value from `0.0f` to `1.0f`.  This `t` represents the ratio in between the two points (`0.0f` being `(0, 0)` and `1.0f` being `(1, 1)`).  For example, the `t` value of `0.5f` would result in the point `(0.5f, 0.5f)`.

Now expanding on this with a less trivial example, consider two points:
`var a = Vector2(1.0f, -1.0f)` and `var b = Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f)`. The result of `Lerp(a, b, 0.5f)` is `Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f)` because this is the halfway point.  Let's call the answer `c`.  The equation that gives us the answer is `c = a + (0.5f * (b - a))`.  This comes from a basic understanding of linear algebra, where two points subtracted from eachother result in a vector, and adding a vector to a point gives another point.

Okay so now onto makeing this code actually work the way you want it to.  Your script could look something like this:

```
float moveTime = 10.0f; // In seconds
float moveTimer = 0.0f; // Used for keeping track of time

bool moving = false; // Flag letting us know if we're moving

float heightChange = 10.0f; // This is the delta

// These will be assigned when a collision occurs
Vector3 target; // our target position
Vector3 startPos; // our starting position

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!moving)
    {
        // We set the target to be ten units above our current position
        target = transform.position + Vector3.up * heightChange;

        // And save our start position (because our actual position will be changing)
        startPos = transform.position;

        // Set the flag so that the movement starts
        moving = true;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    // If we're currently moving and the movement hasn't finished
    if (moving && moveTimer < moveTime)
    {
        // Accumulate the frame time, making the timer tick up
        moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;


        // calculate our ratio ("t")
        float t = moveTimer / moveTime;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, target, t);
    }
    else
    {
        // We either haven't started moving, or have finished moving
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jordan Ellis this realy doing the work, you explained very well, simple and direct. Have one question regard to this. well, i need to put the script in my camera so how can i make this triger to be other object trigger.

exemple : i have 1 box (triger), my player is climbing and when he hit that trigger my camera move smoothly there, so he can see more of the map. (sorry for my english =P)

Comment: Can you help, with your code?  i changed my mind, and what i want is basicly this: A player jump when he hits a BoxCollider2D that i made in MainCamera, this code happen, but it only work once, cus we need to set moving = false; again, and i dont know how i can put i tried diferent ways and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i Set script on trigger, then I add a game object cam, then i drag camera to script , and add cam. in transform.. ty for ur help!! =)

public class CameraUp : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject cam;

float moveTime = 10.0f; // In seconds
float moveTimer = 0.0f; // Used for keeping track of time

bool moving = false; // Flag letting us know if we're moving

float heightChange = 10.0f; // This is the delta

// These will be assigned when a collision occurs
Vector3 target; // our target position
Vector3 startPos; // our starting position


void Start()
{


}


void Update()
{

    // If we're currently moving and the movement hasn't finished
    if (moving && moveTimer < moveTime)
    {
        // Accumulate the frame time, making the timer tick up
        moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;


        // calculate our ratio ("t")
        float t = moveTimer / moveTime;

        cam.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, target, t);
    }
    else
    {
        // We either haven't started moving, or have finished moving
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!moving)
    {
        // We set the target to be ten units above our current position
        target = transform.position + Vector3.up * heightChange;

        // And save our start position (because our actual position will be changing)
        startPos = cam.transform.position;

        // Set the flag so that the movement starts
        moving = true;
    }
}
```

}